# Need help identifying a flag from La Jolla, California

Tags: california, san-diego

[image: mysterious flag]

I need help identifying the blue flag in this image, provided by [Google Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/@32.8735017,-117.2377522,3a,40.4y,292.19h,103.31t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sDZPJX1hvshkVySaHMZIzCg!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo2.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DDZPJX1hvshkVySaHMZIzCg%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D115.40573%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656?shorturl=1), centered on Gilman drive in La Jolla, San Diego, California. The flag appears to have a few yellow stars and a ribbon with some text on it.

Looking at the overall pattern across the four flags, it seems that each flag represents a place that is accommodated within the one represented by the adjacent flag to the left (e.g. California is within the United States and the rightmost flag is of the campus of University of California San Diego that is within both the United States and California).

If the pattern holds, whatever is represented by the blue flag must be within California and larger than UCSD. This is, however, a blind guess on my side and it is possible that the blue flag is completely unrelated to the other three flags.

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to see due to the lack of wind, but based on the stars and colors, it looks similar to [the UC System Flag](https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/us_u_cal.html), which would indeed be a flag representing something within California and larger than UCSD: the University of California.

According to that page, the flag was designed in 1958, but as it no longer appears on the [linked UC branding site](http://brand.universityofcalifornia.edu/), it may not be used that frequently anymore. A clearer color version (which looks like a slightly different, newer version in fact) can be found at the bottom of [this document from UCLA](http://www.eventsprotocol.ucla.edu/documents/UCLA%20Flag%20Protocol%20for%20Special%20Events.pdf), where it is also called the "University Flag" and the "President's Flag."

Comment: From the street view linked in the question, the flag display is on the UCSD campus, in the Gilman Drive median strip opposite the visitor information center.